# Comma usage with the coordinating conjunction "or"

Tags: commas

This is the sentence I was having trouble with, using no punctuation:

> Clearly not everyone has been as lucky as me or been able to afford
>   to attend such institutions and have such training.

This is what I have come up with:

> Clearly, not everyone has been as lucky as me or, been able to afford
>   to attend such institutions and have such training.

I was concerned, primarily, as to whether the comma would come before or after the "or". It just looks funny to me. Perhaps I could phrase it better?
Appreciate any help.

Comment: If you use the commas to indicate a pause- as you would use when speaking that sentence aloud- then it makes more sense for the comma to come before the "or".

Answer (score 1):

> Clearly not everyone has been as lucky as me or been able to afford to attend such institutions and have such training.

The ease of reading might be improved:

> Clearly, not everyone has had my luck in being able to afford such institutions and have such training.

Avoiding the phrase "lucky as me" is probably good. It is more acceptable today to use the object form *me*, in a use like this, than it once was, but I try to avoid it. And the back to back infinitives *to afford to attend* are a little awkward.

If you wish to keep your original wording, the comma should be placed after"me" :

> Clearly not everyone has been as lucky as me, or been able to afford to attend such institutions and have such training.